# Where does the name Kino come from?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

In *Stargate Universe*, one of the central themes is Eli often filming the rest of the crew on Kinos (remote controlled flying cameras). When they're first introduced (S01E03), Eli says;

> I'm calling it a Kino after, you know...

before being cut off by Lt Scott. Every time in that episode he is cut off from elaborating on how he came up with the name. Being that he is an archetypal scifi nerd, there is presumably somewhere that inspires the name.

My question is, where does Eli take the name Kino from?

Comment: ["Кино" (Kino)](https://translate.google.com/#ru/en/kino) is the Russian word for cinema/films. Make of it what you will :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [MGM Website](http://stargate.mgm.com/view/character/171/embed_vid/1045/embed_vid/1051/index.html) indicates that Eli was referring to the term **[Kino-Pravda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kino-Pravda)** (literally in Russian "*movie-truth*")

> The Kino, **named as such by Eli in reference to Russia’s Kino-Pravda in
>   the 1920s,** is an unmanned remote exploratory device believed to have
>   been used by the Ancients in a similar way the SGC use MALPS.

---

There's a slightly larger reference in the [original script](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Stargate/SGU/Stargate_Universe_1x01-02_-_Pilot.pdf)

[image: shot of the original script rading "I was calling it a Kino, you know, after the Russian"]

and in the [novelisation](https://terescia.com/stargateuniversefan/2011/01/air-a-stargate-universe-book-tie-in-novel/)

> Scott peered at it and saw a bobbing first-person view of a corridor;
>   the image had to be coming from the lens he’d seen on the front of the
>   sphere. It’s a camera.
>
> Flying camera, Eli corrected. **I was gonna call it a Kino, you know,
>   after the Russian word for....**

Answer (score 6):

Kino is the [Russian word](https://translate.google.com/#ru/en/kino) for both "cinema" and "film[s]". I thought it was just a generic punt on Russian culture at first, but then I googled up what appears to be the ["official" page for *Stargate*](http://stargate.mgm.com/view/character/171/embed_vid/1045/embed_vid/1051/index.html), and it appears that Eli named those probes after the [1920 newsreel](https://archive.org/stream/kinohistoryofrus00jayl#page/160/mode/2up) series ["Kino-Pravda"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kino-Pravda):

> The Kino, named as such by Eli in reference to Russia’s Kino-Pravda in the 1920s, is an unmanned remote exploratory device believed to have been used by the Ancients in a similar way the SGC use MALPS.

Comment: You get a +1, and you were certainly first. But Valorum included a shot of the script.